# Error: MVC 5 mobile modal window

Tags: jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-5, runtime-error

Error Pup Up Dialog ASP.MVC 5

I am developing a modal window for my application.

I 'm doing all that is necessary for the display, but an error is generated at run-time.

I used two methods: data-role = " Dialog" and data-role = " Pupup " but both generate an error when running.
 the error referred to preventDefault ();

> Error Description : 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error : Object does not support property or method " preventDefault " ==> this error is generated during the use of data-role = " pupup".

During the use of data-role = " Dialog", no event is generated.

Comment: @orde why did you change the title from English to French?

Comment: @tmg: Unless I'm mistaken, I didn't.  Auguste did, but I may have inadvertently approved his edit.  It's reverted now.

Comment: @orde,@tmg: One of you have mobile modal source, it developped many of examples but they all not working. All example generate the preventDefault Error